# Custom Google Sign In Button React.js

Tags: reactjs, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

Is it possible to add custom styling to the Google sign-in button when using the Google JavaScript API?

You can currently render a Google sign-in button using the provided `google.accounts.id.renderButton` method, but I want the text to just be `Google` and for there to be no border around the Google button icon.

```
google.accounts.id.renderButton(buttonRef, buttonOptions)
```

Another thing that I tried was using a button element that called a `signIn` callback when pressed, but this ends up causing a 404 bad request error. Would this method still be worth digging deeper into?

```
<button onClick={signIn}>Google</button>
```

```
const signIn = useCallback(async () => {
    const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
      client_id: clientID,
      callback: (response) => {
        void callback(response.access_token);
      },
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    });
    client.requestAccessToken();
  }, [callback, clientID]);
```